# Error The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception with C#, Opencv and EmguCv

Tags: c#

i have writen simple progam to face detectedin VS 2010 in C# using EmguCV but I am getting the following exception:

```
The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
```

im trying to fix this follow link: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception

i copied all dll but still error.

i use window 7 pro x86, VS 2010, EmguCV2.4.2 and follow this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjoutNR2DQ

help me!

Comment: You should include the *full* stack trace from the exception, including the nested exception. (InnerException)

Comment: The `InnerException` probably tells you exactly what the problem is; what does the `InnerException` say?

Comment: i inluded full stack :(

Answer (score 0):

@Marc Gravell: this is my proplem

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateCameraCapture(Int32 index)
at Emgu.CV.Capture..ctor(Int32 camIndex)
at Emgu.CV.Capture..ctor()
at WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\khtn\new\do an\project\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs:line 45
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsApplication2
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///D:/khtn/new/do%20an/project/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Emgu.CV
Assembly Version: 2.4.2.1777
Win32 Version: 2.4.2.1777
CodeBase: file:///D:/khtn/new/do%20an/project/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/Emgu.CV.DLL
----------------------------------------
Emgu.Util
Assembly Version: 2.4.2.1777
Win32 Version: 2.4.2.1777
CodeBase: file:///D:/khtn/new/do%20an/project/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/Emgu.Util.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
CodeBase: file:///G:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Emgu.CV.UI
Assembly Version: 2.4.2.1777
Win32 Version: 2.4.2.1777
CodeBase: file:///D:/khtn/new/do%20an/project/WindowsFormsApplication2/WindowsFormsApplication2/bin/Debug/Emgu.CV.UI.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

    <configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Your detailed error message should be included as part of your question, not given as an "answer".